# as_tibble() not working as expected

Tags: r, tibble

I am attempting the exercise in [R for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html#two-categorical-variables) (7.5.2.1, #2): *Use geom_tile() together with dplyr to explore how average flight delays vary by destination and month of year. What makes the plot difficult to read? How could you improve it?*

First, transmute columns.

```
library(nycflights13)
foo <- nycflights13::flights %>%
  transmute(tot_delay = dep_delay + arr_delay, m = month, d = dest) %>%
  filter(!is.na(tot_delay)) %>%
  group_by(m, d) %>%
  summarise(avg_delay = mean(tot_delay))
```

Now **foo** appears to be a data frame based on the 'Source' output.

```
> foo
Source: local data frame [1,112 x 3]
Groups: m [?]

       m     d avg_delay
   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1      1   ALB 76.571429
2      1   ATL  8.567982
3      1   AUS 19.017751
4      1   AVL 49.000000
5      1   BDL 32.081081
6      1   BHM 47.043478
7      1   BNA 25.930233
8      1   BOS  2.698517
9      1   BQN  8.516129
10     1   BTV 18.393665
# ... with 1,102 more rows
```

It doesn't appear that **as_tibble** is working, what could I be doing wrong?

```
> as_tibble(foo)
Source: local data frame [1,112 x 3]
Groups: m [?]

       m     d avg_delay
   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1      1   ALB 76.571429
2      1   ATL  8.567982
3      1   AUS 19.017751
4      1   AVL 49.000000
5      1   BDL 32.081081
6      1   BHM 47.043478
7      1   BNA 25.930233
8      1   BOS  2.698517
9      1   BQN  8.516129
10     1   BTV 18.393665
# ... with 1,102 more rows
```

Shouldn't the internals be different for a tibble?

```
> str(foo)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1112 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ m        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ d        : chr  "ALB" "ATL" "AUS" "AVL" ...
 $ avg_delay: num  76.57 8.57 19.02 49 32.08 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol m
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
> str(as_tibble(foo))
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1112 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ m        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ d        : chr  "ALB" "ATL" "AUS" "AVL" ...
 $ avg_delay: num  76.57 8.57 19.02 49 32.08 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol m
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

Note that as_tibble() works as expected

```
> packageDescription("tibble")
Package: tibble
Encoding: UTF-8
Version: 1.3.0

> is_tibble(foo)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Type `str(foo)`. What does it show? If you see `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame'`, it worked

Comment: What versions of the "tidyverse" packages have you got?

Comment: "Now foo is a data frame." is incorrect. `data.frame` doesn't handle groups, and `print.data.frame` doesn't list column types. `foo` is clearly a `tibble` at that point. `local data frame` may be the part confusing you. It doesn't say "local `data.frame`" (note the missing dot).

Comment: Use the `sessionInfo()` function to get package version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - `foo` is a "tibble" and is announced as "A tibble: 112 x 3" in the print:

```
> foo
Source: local data frame [1,112 x 3]
Groups: m [?]

# A tibble: 1,112 x 3
       m     d avg_delay
   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1   ALB 76.571429
 2     1   ATL  8.567982
```

So you possibly have an old version of dplyr. Mine is:

```
> packageDescription("dplyr")
Package: dplyr
Type: Package
Version: 0.5.0
```

And everything else:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0  tibble_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5     R6_2.2.0         assertthat_0.2.0 DBI_0.5-1       
[5] tools_3.3.1      Rcpp_0.12.11     rlang_0.1.1
```

Comment: I have the same version (0.5.0)

Comment: Interesting.  As you can tell neither foo nor as_tibble(foo) show the tibble comment that yours does - do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: I have version 1.3.1 of `tibble`. Maybe that .1 makes alll the difference. *Or some other version difference*.